# Is there a way to avoid infinite loop of dependencies and to pass the correct dependencies to useEffect hook in this case?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook which gets a callback as one of the arguments and calls it in `useEffect`

```
const customHook = (callback: Function) => {
  ...
  useEffect(() => {
    if (something) {
      callback();
    }
  }, [other things, callback]);

  return {values}
}
```

The problem here is that `callback` is a function and causes `useEffect` to run in a loop. EsLint suggested `useCallback` in a parent component. So I decided to wrap this `callback` in a `useCallback` where I am calling my `customHook`.

So I would have something like this in my component:

```
const memoizedCallback = useCallback(() => {
    myFunction(values);
  }, [values, myFunction]);

  const { values } = customHook(memoizedCallback);
```

And here I have my problem - dependencies of `myFunction` are returned from `customHook` and I can not use them before they defined. But I also can not put `memoizedCallback` after `customHook` call because of the same reasons.

And now I am stuck in this infinite loop of dependencies and I am not sure how to solve this, if somehow, without just ignoring eslint warning.

So any ideas and solutions will be much appreciated :)

Comment: If `callback` is something that is dependent on values returned from this custom hook, then you should probably declare this callback inside your custom hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If changing the callback shouldn't cause the `useEffect` block to be executed set the `callback` to a ref:

```
const customHook = (callback: Function) => {
  const fn = useRef(callback);
  
  ...
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fn.current = callback;
  })
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (something) {
      fn.current(); // fn.current?.() if fn.current might be undefined
    }
  }, [something]);

  return {values}
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you. Interesting approach, will have to remember that for the future :)